# How do you compare dictionaries and lists

Tags: python, cs50

I'm attempting to do CS50 Problem DNA, I have some values in a dictionary that I wanna compare with a given csv file to find matches. Here's my code:

```
import sys
import re
import csv
ua = sys.argv[1]
uo = sys.argv[2]
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("ERROR. Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
    exit(1)
chingi = {
"AGATC": 0,
"AATG": 0,
"TATC": 0,
"TTTTTTCT": 0,
"TCTAG": 0,
"GATA": 0, 
"GAAA": 0,
"TCTG": 0,
}
mon = []
f = open(uo , 'r')
ass = csv.reader(f)
for row in ass:
    print(row)

cha = list(row)
for test in chingi:
    count = 0
    while True:
        count+=1
        z = 0
        while z < len(cha):
            u = cha[z].count(test * count)
            z+=1
        if u == 0:
            break
        chingi[test] = count
print(chingi)
bruh = open(ua, 'r')
reader = csv.reader(bruh)
for x in reader:
    for y in range(0, 9):
        print(x[y])
        if chingi["TTTTTTCT"] == x[y]:
            print("match found!!!!!!!!!!!!!1")
        else:
            print("no match")
```

Problem is i dont know how to go about doing the comparing part and this is as far as i have gotten.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What are you comparing? Do you want to check which dictionary keys are in your csv?

Comment: Yes exactly, but as you see in the dictionary there's more than one pattern that I need to compare. Is there a way I can link or upload the csv file? I'm new here.

Comment: Exactly which dictionary are you trying to compare to the CSV?

Comment: Please post the CSV files (or part of them) so we can test.

Comment: @MrMayouta you can edit your question and paste 2 or 3 rows of the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think comparing works, I think instead you could pull items out from both. For example: `exdictionary[insert key here]` to get the dictionary result and `exlist[insert slice here]` to get the list result. You can definitely compare strings.